# Ruby on Rails id column not generated after db:migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a course on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/rails-with-active-record/) and I'm on my first assignment details of which can be found on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwvt4e6DQqn4dGRBdWU3ZkxLeEU/view) and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwvt4e6DQqn4TnRscERxQm1BeTA/view) link. WHen I ran rspec I found the test cases to be failing, turned out my schema didn't have an ID column in it. In the course it said that when I run migration the ID column is generated automatically just like created_at and updated_at. Anyone has any idea why the id column probably didn't get generated. I know I can overcome the problem by specifying it in a new migration but just wanted to know the reason.

Here's the Schema I currently have:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161108162529) do

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "gender"
    t.integer  "birth_year"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "todo_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "due_date"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "completed",   default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

  create_table "todo_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "list_name"
    t.date     "list_due_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

This is the migrations for todolists:

```
class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :list_name
      t.date :list_due_date

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The model class it generated:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My method that is inserting a record in it in the assignment.rb file as asked:

```
 def create_todolist(params)
      # accept a hash of todolist properties (`:name` and `:due_date`) as an input parameter. Note these are not 100% the same as Model class.
      # use the TodoList Model class to create a new user in the DB
      # return an instance of the class with primary key (`id`), and dates (`created_at` and `updated_at`) assigned
      t1 = TodoList.new
      t1.list_name = params["name"]
      t1.list_due_date = params["due_date"]
      t1.save
      TodoList.first
  end
```

rspec code that is failing:

```
context "rq03.2 assignment code has create_todolist method" do
        it { is_expected.to respond_to(:create_todolist) } 
        it "should create_todolist with provided parameters" do
            expect(TodoList.find_by list_name: "mylist").to be_nil
            due_date=Date.today
            assignment.create_todolist(:name=> 'mylist', :due_date=>due_date)
            testList = TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'
            expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.list_name).to eq "mylist"
            expect(testList.list_due_date).to eq due_date
            expect(testList.created_at).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.updated_at).not_to be_nil
        end
```

Actual message that I get when it fails the test:

Failures:

```
1) Assignment rq03 rq03.2 assignment code has create_todolist method should create_todolist with provided parameters
     Failure/Error: expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:173:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you show us your migrations? They are located in /db/migrate

Comment: How can you say that id column didn't get generated? FYI schema file does not show ID column.

Comment: Updated the original post with all the relevant details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema won't show the ID column. I double checked with one of my rails apps:

`db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
end
```

And when I describe the table in Postgres with `\d users`, I see the `id` column:

```
         Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email                  | character varying           | not null default ''::character varying
 first_name             | character varying           |
 last_name              | character varying           |
```

---

If there is a reason you don't want the ID, you can omit it by passing `id: false` to `create_table`.

```
create_table :users, id: false do |t|
  #...
end
```

Probably a horrible idea on the `users` table :-)

---

### Update

Looks like you are not actually creating a new `TodoList`.

The clue here is in the error: "undefined method 'id' for **`nil:NilClass`**". Your `testList` is nil.

One good tip is to always use the ActiveRecord's "bang" methods in tests. This will cause them to throw an exception if they fail. Which is super helpful when trying to track down errors -- you'll find the place with the **actual** error and not some side effect down the line.

I bet you can update your `create_todolist` to help track this down

```
def create_todolist(params)
  # Updated: To use ActiveRecord create! method. 
  # This will throw an exception if it fails.
  TodoList.create!(list_name: params[:name], due_date: params[:due_date])
end
```

I would also update your spec, by changing:

```
  testList = TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'
```

To use the bang:

```
  testList = TodoList.find_by! list_name: 'mylist'
```

Comment: Hey, I updated the post. Can you now tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but can you tell me what did I do wrong? I thought what I was doing was completely valid.

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong. Using the Active Model methods that return nil instead of raising an exception were just masking the problem. And since you were looking in the wrong place it was confusing. Luckily you were writing tests so it was *much* easier to track it down.